# Add characters or lines from .read() or .readline() to a new array in python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, bioinformatics, fasta

```
Metadata = []
Sequence = []
N=0
with open(file_location) as f: #opens file
    content = f.read() #defines file under content
for char in content:
    if char == ">":
        while char != "\n":
            char.join(metadata[N])
```

I am trying to build a fasta interpreter and and keep getting a "list index out of range" error when trying to parse a FASTA file [(formatted like this)](http://evolutionarygenomics.imim.es/pf/multi_fasta.gif). I'm not sure why python is having trouble storing characters to an array. Can I use list comprehension to define an array that is long enough before opening the file?

Comment: why don't  you use biopython?

Comment: This is for some coursework, we're supposed to do it the hard way. No matter how Asinine.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with `content`, but with `Metadata`. You create it as an empty list, then trying to call its `N`th element.

Initialize it with some values so your program can run.

Comment: I eventually realized I could just `.append()` all my needed output to `metadata`. I was afraid to initialize an empty list of unknown length.